# How can I create a folder on my phone's memory using kivy

Tags: python, android, directory, kivy

I wanna create a folder. Who content some files created by user. But I didn't understand how can to create a folder on my phone's memory.

My folder will be in /storage/emulate/0/Android/data/org.app.test/folder.
I'm trying

```
os.mkdir(str(primary_external_storage_path() + "/Android/data/org.app.test/folder"))
```

But it doesn't work.

Ps : it could be a problem with android's permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will need to ask for storage permissions to be able to access files outside of it's private folder. Below is working example. I changed `os.mkdir` to `os.makedirs` to be able to create parent directories of your path.

main.py

```
from kivy import platform
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.app import App
import os

class TestApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.permissions import Permission, check_permission, request_permissions
            perms = [Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]
            if not all([check_permission(perm) for perm in perms]):
                Factory.MyPermReqPopup().open()

    def popup_close(self):
        from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions
        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
        exit()

    def create_folder_click(self):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
            os.makedirs(str(primary_external_storage_path()) + "/Android/data/org.app.test/folder", exist_ok=True)

TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: root.width, root.height
    Button:
        text: 'create folder'
        on_release: app.create_folder_click()

<MyPermReqPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    on_dismiss: app.popup_close()
    title: 'Please grant storage permission, then launch app again'
    size_hint: (1, 0.3)
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            text: 'OK'
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```